# Print cv::Mat opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to print cv::Mat which contains my image. However whenever I print the Mat using cout, a 2D array printed into  my text file. I want to print one one pixel in one line only. How can i print line wise pixels from cv::Mat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic for_each loop, you could use it to print your data

```
/**
 *@brief implement details of for_each_channel, user should not use this function
 */
template<typename T, typename UnaryFunc>
UnaryFunc for_each_channel_impl(cv::Mat &input, int channel, UnaryFunc func)
{
    int const rows = input.rows;
    int const cols = input.cols;
    int const channels = input.channels();
    for(int row = 0; row != rows; ++row){
        auto *input_ptr = input.ptr<T>(row) + channel;
        for(int col = 0; col != cols; ++col){
            func(*input_ptr);
            input_ptr += channels;
        }
    }

    return func;
}
```

use it like

```
for_each_channel_impl<uchar>(input, 0, [](uchar a){ std::cout<<(size_t)a<<", "; });
```

you could do some optimization to continuous channel, then it may looks like

```
/**
 *@brief apply stl like for_each algorithm on a channel
 *
 * @param
 *  T : the type of the channel(ex, uchar, float, double and so on)
 * @param
 *  channel : the channel need to apply for_each algorithm
 * @param
 *  func : Unary function that accepts an element in the range as argument
 *
 *@return :
 *  return func
 */
template<typename T, typename UnaryFunc>
inline UnaryFunc for_each_channel(cv::Mat &input, int channel, UnaryFunc func)
{
    if(input.channels() == 1 && input.isContinuous()){
        return for_each_continuous_channels<T>(input, func);
    }else{
        return for_each_channel_impl<T>(input, channel, func);
    }
}
```

This kind of generic loopsave me a lot of times, I hope you find it helpful.If there are
any bugs, or you have better idea, please tell me.

I would like to design some generic algorithms for opencl too, sadly it do not support 
template, I hope one day CUDA will become an open standard, or opencl will support template.

This works for any number of channels as long as the channels type are base on byte, non-byte
channel may not work.